# Problem running python script at boot raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi

I'm having an insane amount of trouble with my script at startup, I've tried countless ways and spent hours trying to get this to work.

I have a python script that I need to run at startup. However, it needs access to the internet, so I have to wait for the network.

I have tried many ways in the several tutorials I have tried, with crontab, by making a service with systemd, with rc.local however none of these have worked.

The only way that I was able to work was by doing a .desktop Desktop Entry, but that only worked for me while I had an external monitor plugged in, and my raspberry pi will be running without one.

Also, I was able to make my script run using the service method and now the rc.local

by adding this line:

```
sudo bash -c '/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Projects/capstone/main.py > /home/pi/capstone.log 2>&1' &
```

However, in the python script that I am trying to run, I have the following code:

```
os.system("sudo killall servod")
time.sleep(1)   
os.system('sudo ~/PiBits/ServoBlaster/user/./servod')
```

And for some reason, it's not running my script correctly because I get the following error in my logs:

```
servod: no process found
sudo: /root/PiBits/ServoBlaster/user/./servod: command not found
```

The first one is expected because I run sudo killall servod when it may or may not be started, but the second one "Command not found" is what is the issue, if that bit of code doesn't get executed my program doesn't work.

Anyone out there could help me out with this?

Comment: Try creating a `@reboot`  cron under the root user: https://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/sandyj/running-scripts-at-boot

Comment: @PedroLobito I have tried with cron and I did not get any success

Comment: The following path doesn't seem correct to me `~/PiBits/ServoBlaster/user/./servod`

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
os.system('sudo ~/PiBits/ServoBlaster/user/./servod')
```

with:

```
os.system('sudo /home/pi/PiBits/ServoBlaster/user/./servod')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Double check the path and try to use absolute path
2. Make sure you script has permission 644

You can also try to copy the script to /etc/init.d and run it as init.d script.  You do need to add the following to your script:

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO

sudo chmod +x <yourscript.py>
sudo update-rc.d <yourscript.py> defaults
```

Answer (score 0):

One way you could easily wait for the network inside your python script is to ping a server until successful -- in this case Google.

```
def wait_for_network():
    while os.system("ping -c 1 8.8.8.8") != 0:
        time.sleep(1)
    return
```

As for running the script at startup, I recommend editing `/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and adding your python script in there with the format

```
@python3 home/pi/your_script.py
```